# How to print directly without open print dialog box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to print a PDF file using this code, but  I don't want open the confirm print page.Can u help me ?

```
    function PrintRdlcReport() {
        var divtoPrint = document.getElementById('ReportViewer1_fixedTable');
        var newwin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
        newwin.document.open();
        $("#ReportViewer1_ctl07_img").remove();
        $("#ReportViewer1_ToggleParam_img").remove();
        $("#ReportViewer1_ctl05").remove();
        newwin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()" style=" border: 1px  #000000 solid; font-family: verdana ;font-size: 14px ;">' + divtoPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
        newwin.document.close();
    }
```